# Multer does not receive form data

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

1. 

```
export const submitClass = ({ classData }) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const { userAccessToken } = getToken()
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("idUser", classData.idUser)
            formData.append("certificationName", classData.certificationName)
            formData.append("classAdvantages", JSON.stringify(classData.classAdvantages))
            formData.append("classDescription", classData.classDescription)
            formData.append("classFeePercentage", classData.classFeePercentage)
            formData.append("classLevel", classData.classLevel)
            formData.append("classPrice", classData.classPrice)
            formData.append("classSlug", classData.classSlug)
            formData.append("classURLTrailer", classData.classURLTrailer)
            formData.append("classname", classData.classname)
            formData.append("isFree", classData.isFree)
            formData.append("isLive", classData.isLive)
            formData.append("poster", classData.poster.posterFile)
            formData.append("seminarDate", classData.seminarDate)
            formData.append("totalVideo", classData.totalVideo)
            const response = await axios.post(endpoint.SUBMIT_CLASS, formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`
                }
            })
            const { msg: message } = response.data
            import(`helpers/toast`).then(({ successToast }) => {
                successToast(message)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                const { msg: errorMessage, errLevel } = error.response.data
                if (errLevel > 1) import(`helpers/toast`).then(({ errorToast }) => {
                    errorToast(errorMessage)
                })
            }

        }
    }

}
```

2. 

```
    const {
           idUser,
           isLive,
           classname,
           classSlug,
           classLevel,
           classURLTrailer,
           classPrice,
           classFeePercentage,
           classAdvantages,
           totalVideo,
           certificationName,
           seminarDate,
           classDescription
          } = req.body
            console.log(req.body)
```

When i console.log **req.body**, all of my data are sent except **totalVideo**, i dont understand why **totalVideo** is not sent. When i put `formData.append("totalVideo", classData.totalVideo)` above **(not in the last line)** it is sent but the last line become not sent. Anyone know why? Is multer has maximum limit to receive formData?

Please let me know if anyone know the answer. Thanks and appreciate it!

EDIT: this is my route file

```
const express = require('express')
const db = require("../../database/db.js")
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const authenticateUser = require('../../middleware/authenticateUser.js')
const { submitClass } = require('../../controllers/admin/class.js')
const { CLASS_POSTER_FILE_PATH } = require('../../constants/path.js')
const submitClassValidation = require('../../validations/submitClass.js')
const formatFilename = require('../../helpers/formatFilename.js')
const checkValidURL = require('../../helpers/checkValidURL.js')
const { CLASS_FEE_PERCENTAGE, CLASS_TOTAL_VIDEO, CLASS_PRICE } = require('../../constants/class.js')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        const idUser = req.body.idUser
        const dirClassUser = `${CLASS_POSTER_FILE_PATH}/${idUser}`
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirClassUser)) fs.mkdirSync(dirClassUser)
        callback(null, dirClassUser)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, formatFilename(file))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024, //1mb
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        const {
            idUser,
            isLive,
            classname,
            classSlug,
            classLevel,
            classURLTrailer,
            classPrice,
            classFeePercentage,
            classAdvantages,
            totalVideo,
            certificationName,
            seminarDate,
            classDescription
        } = req.body
        console.log(req.body)
        // TOTAL VIDEO IS NOT SENT
        if (!idUser) return callback(null, false)
        if (classname.length < 3) return callback(null, false)
        if (classSlug.length < 3) return callback(null, false)
        if (!classLevel) return callback(null, false)
        const isclassURLValid = checkValidURL(classURLTrailer)
        if (!isclassURLValid) return callback(null, false)
        if (!classPrice) return callback(null, false)
        if (+classPrice < CLASS_PRICE.MIN) return callback(null, false)
        if (!classFeePercentage) return callback(null, false)
        if (+classFeePercentage < CLASS_FEE_PERCENTAGE.MIN) return callback(null, false)
        if (!(+isLive)) {
            if (!totalVideo) return callback(null, false)
            if (+totalVideo < CLASS_TOTAL_VIDEO.MIN) return callback(null, false)
        }
        if (certificationName.length < 10) return callback(null, false)
        if (+isLive) if (!seminarDate) return callback(null, false)
        if (classDescription.length < 250) return callback(null, false)
        for (const classAdvantage of JSON.parse(classAdvantages)) {
            if (classAdvantage.value.length < 10) return callback(null, false)
        }


        db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log(`multer Connection id ${connection.threadId}`)
            connection.release()
            connection.query('SELECT id_user, class_slug FROM mentor_class WHERE id_user = ? AND class_slug = ?', [idUser, classSlug], async function (err, currentClass, fields) {
                if (err) throw err
                const mimetypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/JPEG', 'image/JPG', 'image/PNG']
                if (currentClass.length > 0 || !mimetypes.includes(file.mimetype)) return callback(null, false)
                return callback(null, true)
            })
        })
    }
}).single('poster')

const classAdminRouter = express.Router()
classAdminRouter.post('/', [authenticateUser, upload, submitClassValidation], submitClass)

module.exports = classAdminRouter
```

**SOLVED:**

The problem is in the order of my formData. All of my data must be sent before sending my file data. You can check **here https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/322**. Great!

Comment: can you share router config. Multer reads line by line, so if you are trying to access in the multer middleware it needs to be last, for others like in next middleware you will have all params

Comment: I added my router file code. Can you check pls. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer of this problem thanks! https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/322